# Time complexity of an+b = O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I am reading "Introduction to algorithms" and got stuck at Chapter 3 where the authors say that "What may be more surprising is that when a > 0, any linear function `an + b` is
in O(n^2)" 
Can anybody explain how to prove that?

Comment: Could you provide a more specific location than "at Chapter 3", or at least explain the notation "an C b" in this context?

Answer (score 2):

A linear function `an + b` is `O(n^2)` by definition: for sufficiently large `n`, `an + b` is less than `cn^2` with constant, for example `c = 1`.

Note that `O(n^2)` is an upper bound but not a tight one. A not-so-tight bound is not very useful once you can prove a tighter bound (`O(n)` upper bound in this case).

Answer (score 1):

For an intuition, the idea of "big O" notation is that starting from sufficiently large input, the cost function does not grow faster than O(...). That is all, it's just an upper bound.

The linear function does not grow faster than a quadratic function, cubic function, exponential function etc. They all grow faster, hence `an + b` is `O(n^2)`, but also `O(n^3)`, `O(2^n)`, `O(n!)` etc.

However, it grows faster than logarithm - so you cannot say that it is `O(log n)`.